# How to deploy NuxtJs Application on Apache and access it with IP-URL instead of a domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, nuxt.js

Please note, this is my first nuxt-app trying to deploy on a staging server. We have a staging AWS server where many web applications are deployed as follows.

- http://0.0.0.0/app1/public (Laravel)
- http://0.0.0.0/app2 (static)
- http://0.0.0.0/app3/public/api (Lumen)
- http://0.0.0.0/app4/public (VueJs Static)
- etc
- http://0.0.0.0/app5 (Tried NuxtJs Universal SSR) **failed**

Note: SERVER: AWS instance has Ubuntu 18.04 with apache2

Now I want to deploy NuxtJs Universal Application (SSR), I have studied many articles, tried but failed.

**What I have done so far:**

1. Moved my all code to /var/www/html/app5
2. followed all the steps https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/deployment/deployment-pm2
3. stuck, what to do next, and don't know how to access it in a browser with IP server.
4. pm2 list, command gives me the following result.

[image]

**Progress Update:**

I have finally found a new way to configure it on the main IP with virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName http://0.0.0.0

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app5

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**My steps to configure NuxtJs app on IP-URL:**

1. Created a new virtual host as above named nuxtjs.conf
2. a2dissite 000-default.conf, it was pointing to /var/www/html
3. a2ensite nuxtjs.conf
4. a2enmod proxy_http and a2enmod proxy
5. systemctl restart apache2
6. Yahoo! my main server IP-URL (http://0.0.0.0) was pointed to NuxtJs-application running perfectly :-)
7. But the problem was my all other websites stopped because they were running with 000-default.conf virtual host.

Please guide, what should be configuration, I don't want to close my all websites, they should be running as I mentioned at the start as http://0.0.0.0/name-of-web. How can I run the NuxtJs application as ip-url/app-name?

Comment: Try to `npm run start` on the `dist` directory.

Comment: It is already running via pm2, but I am not sure how can I now access it on what URL :-(

Answer (score 0):

After a long time, my question was alone, so I decided to give it a partner with my answer, part a joke I have found the solution, and the following is my finding. Please update it if you have the more appropriate knowledge.

1. Enabled 81 port via AWS console.
2. Added following configuration in the `nuxt.config.js` to run the application on a specific port locally in the server.

   ```
   server: {
     port: 43411
   }
   ```
3. Updated virtual host as follows.

   ```
    NameVirtualHost *:81
    <VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName http://0.0.0.0

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/app5

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:43411/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:43411/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>
   ```
4. Now I can access my nuxt-app on an IP URL as follows, along with all other deployed websites on this server.
   http://0.0.0.0:81/